# Calling External Web Service from Smart Contract

Tags: external-api

Trying to find a way to invoke a external web service to perform any operation based on some action on the smart contract.

Request to share  details as to how to perform the same.

Answer (score 1):

Oraclize provides an interface to talk to external system like web api /web services.

Links / Documentation  : https://docs.oraclize.it/#home

Getting started with Oraclize : https://medium.com/@rsripathi781/etherum-using-oraclize-with-solidity-485e40283363

Oraclize does charge ethers for every request you make.

Comment: Thanks for sharing will have a look. But looking more of a way to do it rather using a third party solution.